# I have the blank page of backend after migration the Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I have the big problem. I have migrated Prestashop on the new server with Akeeba solo (type of file jpa). After migration the front-end work fine but the back-end page is blank. You have any idea what is the problem?

The online shop is: https://pajac.com
Backend is https://pajac.com/adminPaj

Thank you advance!

Comment: At first read this topic: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/575132-how-to-enable-debug-mode-on-prestashop-17-and-older-versions-turn-on-error-reporting-blank-page/

Comment: are you in debug mode?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, i'm in debug mode.  if (!defined('_PS_MODE_DEV_')) {
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
}

Comment: But I do not have much experience in Prestashop.

Comment: Are you sure that your PHP version conforms to your prestashop's engine requirement?

Comment: Hi @GerganaKostadinova . Join Prestashop Group on Facebook and also ask here https://www.facebook.com/prestashark.eu/ Stack is not good place to solve this kind of problems. Regards!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I solved the problem.